# UWP webView equivalent of addJavascriptInterface() from Android

Tags: javascript, c#, android, webview, win-universal-app

I would like to now if there are some equivalent of `addJavascriptInterface()` from `Android` in `UWP`. From what I have read, first the script must be invoke through the method `InvokeScript` and in the `JavaScript` function `window.external.notify()` must be called. But I don´t want to invoke the javascript function, I just want to "wait" until the javaScriptFunction is called,. It would be like a listener of Javascript functions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found what I wanted, this is the solution, use the [`WebView.AddWebAllowedObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.addweballowedobject) method.

See also, “[Accessing the Windows Runtime in WebView | WebView Class (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls) - Windows UWP applications | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#accessing-the-windows-runtime-in-webview)”

Answer (score 2):

There is `ScriptNotify` event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx) which occures when JavaScript function `window.external.notify()` is invoked on the web-page. So you should add `window.external.notify()` calls to the JavaScript-functions you want to listen.